# Uncentred Lebesgue Differentiation Theorem

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral

According to Lebesgue's Differentiation Theorem, if $f \in L^1(\mathbb{R})$ then for almost every $x \in \mathbb{R}$:

$f(x) = \lim_{t \rightarrow 0^+} \frac{1}{2t} \int^{x+t}_{x-t} f$;

my question is, does the following hold:

$\lim_{t \rightarrow 0^+} sup\{ |f(x) - f_I| : I \subset \mathbb{R} \} = 0 $ ?

$I$ is an interval of length $t$ that contains $x$;
$f_I = \frac{1}{|I|} \int_{I} f$.

Seems to me that if $I$ is a very small interval then (for almost every $x \in \mathbb{R}$) $f_I$ 'ought' to be close to $f(x)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lebesgue's differentiation theorem says a bit more: for almost every $x \in \mathbf R$ you have $$\lim_{t \to 0^+} \frac 1{2t} \int_{x-t}^{x+t} |f(y) - f(x)| \, dy = 0.$$ For any such point $x$, an interval $I$ containing $x$ with length $t$ will satisfy $$\frac 1{|I|} \int_I |f(y) - f(x)| \, dy \le \frac 1{|I|} \int_{x-t}^{x+t} |f(y) - f(x)| \, dy = 2 \frac{1}{2t} \int_{x-t}^{x+t} |f(y) - f(x)| \, dy$$ which tends to $0$ as $|I| \to 0$.